# Python strange issue brainstorming - why is ONE line not executing SOME of the time?

Tags: python

This is one of the trickiest issues I have ever been faced with in my 15 year programming career.

The setup is a deployed Django app. We have a feature which allow users to invite other users.

I loop through a list of email addresses. In each iteration of the loop, I do a bunch of things in order to provision the user in our system, send them a welcome email, and record this event in 3rd party systems.

The body of the loop looks like this:

```
try:
    # ... some other code ...

    send_new_user_welcome_email(
        user,
        self.inviter,
        temp_password,
        welcome_message=welcome_message,
        is_reviewer=True
    )

    analytics_record_event(
        self.inviter,
        EVENT_INVITED_USER,
        invite_type='reviewer',
        invited_email=email
    )

    record_customer_io_invited_someone(
        self.inviter, 
        email
    )
except:
    logger.exception('While inviting user "%s"' % email)
```

The problem I am seeing is that occasionally (about once every 50 or so times someone invites one or more users), the `analytics_record_event` function does not seem to execute. It does not raise any exceptions. It is simply skipped over and the next line executes.

In order to diagnose the issue, I have added logging to the `analytics_record_event` function to log to a file every time it gets called:

```
def analytics_record_event(user,
                           event_name,
                           skip_mixpanel=False,
                           skip_preact=False,
                           **properties):
    username = user.username if hasattr(user, 'username') else user
    logger.info(
        u'analytics_record_event called for user %s and event "%s"' % (username, event_name)
    )
```

I am looking for ideas as to how this could be. I have already spent a lot of time looking into this, and my findings are below:

- `send_new_user_welcome_email` gets called. Our SMTP server logs confirm that the email goes out. An internal email log collaborates this as well.
- `record_customer_io_invited_someone` gets called. The event data exists for that user in the external system.
- No entries for the `u'analytics_record_event...` log statement can be found in my log files for the times when this is failing. At other times, when this function is executing fine (majority of the time), the log entries are there.
- No exception logs for the above `except` statement exist.
- No un-handled exceptions in this timeframe are found.
- When it fails, it fails for each iteration of the loop for every email being invited as part of the whole invite users request. It fails for every iteration of the loop. There has not been one case where an invite request has been sent, and it worked for some of the invited emails and failed for some within that one request.
- It does not seem to be data-related. The email addresses do not contain any strange characters.

It looks like occasionally, the call to `analytics_record_event` is simply not being made. This is causing me great grief. If anyone can suggest a path of investigation for this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just to rule out the stupid mistakes first (since those are the ones at least I make most often, and have the hardest time debugging…), your logger is configured to level `info` or `debug`, right?

Comment: I do not know much about Django, but could it be that somehow _two_ versions of this script are deployed, and once in a while the wrong one is being executed, lacking that function call?

Comment: @tobias_k: That was my next suggestion. If you've got this deployed on multiple servers, and your deployment script is failing on one of them, one could have old code. Or if you're using a forking server with live update, some of the forks will still be running old code until they get recycled, which, depending on your config, could take a long time.

Comment: @abarnert: He does mention that it shows up in his log files when the function is executing fine. So logging is probably configured correctly.

Nonetheless, I'd also attempt to rule out logging. Write to a file directly and compare that with your logs.

Comment: @MaikHoepfel: If we could rule out the possibility that the log level is debug 49/50 times and notice 1/50, then knowing that it shows up in the log files when the function is executing fine would tell us something… (Writing to a file directly, as you suggest, is a good way to rule that out…)

Comment: The problem is not only that the message is not making it into the log file. That function also sends data to 3rd party analytics processors, and the data is not making it there either (during the calls when no logging is done). Otherwise, the function works well and sends the analytics and logs to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be surprising and extremely mundane.

The code I was tracing through was part of the standard user creation process in the system I am working on. However, there is a bulk-creation process based on CSV files which does analogous work. `analytics_record_event` was not being called in that process.

Lessons for the future:
- I thought I was being clever and covering a lot of ground by putting in a function decorator on `analytics_record_event`. The results of this made me even more puzzled, leading to this desperate plea for help :). Had I added a log statement before and after the call to `analytics_record_event` in this particular function, I would have realized earlier that it is not being called at all! KISS at work.